# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, express, ionic3, mean-stack

Here by using `GET` method, I'm getting the applied jobs list. This code is from `appliedJobsPage`

```
this.getjobs.getAppliedjobList().subscribe(data => {
      this.appliedjobs = data;
    })
```

This is my provider page `getJobs`

```
getAppliedjobList() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/appliedjobs',{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.jobslist = data;
    });
  }
```

I'm getting error as

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?
```

Comment: Remove the `subscribe` call in `getAppliedjobList`. Just return the Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having this error because you have already subscribed to the observable.

```
map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.jobslist = data;
    });
```

If you're using angular version 5 or later you don't need this `map(res => res.json())`. 
At any rate, you need to remove the subscription to the observable in your service so that you can subscribe to the observable in your component. Remove the following in your service:

```
.subscribe(data => {
          this.jobslist = data;
        });
```

Comment: I'm using ionic 3 which is angular 4. Yes, still I get the error. I get the error in `appliedJobspage`

Comment: You have to keep : `map(res => res.json())` And you remove the subscription as indicated in the answer. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue :)

Comment: But when i `post` data and when go to the `appliedJobsPage` the `GET` method does not reflect the changes...

Comment: There might be an error in the way you're handling the post request server-side. Use the console to see if the post request completes well